# PITest with gradle Unsupported class file major version

Tags: java, gradle, build.gradle, mutation-testing, pitest

I'm trying to get pitest running in [this java gradle project](https://github.com/JimLynchCodes/Gradle-Pitest-Example) but having a *VERY* difficult time...

I have at least two problems: one about packages and one about Java versions.

1)

The first issue is that my project is set up with a public class not contained within any package. I know it is kind of an antipattern to do this, but for a project with only a single java class and test file it seems unnecessary to have an additional package container.

Anyway, it seems like pitest cannot file the file without it being inside of a package. Any I wrong here? Is there  something I can put for the "testClasses" value that it would pick up my Lasagna class?

2)

Ok, so in the code here I have declared the "LP" package for my Lasagna class and updated my `build.gradle` with this pitest block:

```
pitest {
    targetClasses = ['LP*']  // by default "${project.group}.*"
    threads = 4
    outputFormats = ['XML', 'HTML']
    timestampedReports = false
    junit5PluginVersion = '1.2.0'
}
```

The problem though is when I run `gradle pitest` I get an "Unsupported class version" Error...

> Task :pitest FAILED
> 11:17:45 AM PIT >> INFO : Verbose logging is disabled. If you encounter a problem, please enable it before reporting an issue.
> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unsupported class file major version 65
> at org.pitest.reloc.asm.ClassReader.(ClassReader.java:199)
> at org.pitest.reloc.asm.ClassReader.(ClassReader.java:180)
> at org.pitest.reloc.asm.ClassReader.(ClassReader.java:166)
> at org.pitest.classinfo.ClassInfoVisitor.getClassInfo(ClassInfoVisitor.java:41)
> at org.pitest.classinfo.Repository.nameToClassInfo(Repository.java:70)
> at org.pitest.classinfo.Repository.fetchClass(Repository.java:60)
> at org.pitest.classinfo.NameToClassInfo.apply(NameToClassInfo.java:17)
> at org.pitest.classinfo.NameToClassInfo.apply(NameToClassInfo.java:7)
> at java.base/java.util.function.Function.lambda$andThen$1(Function.java:88)
> at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$7$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:273)
> at java.base/java.util.ArrayList$ArrayListSpliterator.forEachRemaining(ArrayList.java:1708)
> at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:509)
> at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:499)
> at java.base/java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceOp.evaluateSequential(ReduceOps.java:921)
> at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
> at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.collect(ReferencePipeline.java:682)
> at org.pitest.classpath.CodeSource.getCode(CodeSource.java:44)
> at org.pitest.mutationtest.verify.DefaultBuildVerifier.verify(DefaultBuildVerifier.java:32)
> at org.pitest.mutationtest.tooling.MutationCoverage.verifyBuildSuitableForMutationTesting(MutationCoverage.java:275)
> at org.pitest.mutationtest.tooling.MutationCoverage.runReport(MutationCoverage.java:118)
> at org.pitest.mutationtest.tooling.EntryPoint.execute(EntryPoint.java:129)
> at org.pitest.mutationtest.tooling.EntryPoint.execute(EntryPoint.java:57)
> at org.pitest.mutationtest.commandline.MutationCoverageReport.runReport(MutationCoverageReport.java:98)
> at org.pitest.mutationtest.commandline.MutationCoverageReport.main(MutationCoverageReport.java:45)

When I run `gradle -v` I get this output:

> ---
>
> ### Gradle 8.3
>
> Build time:   2023-08-17 07:06:47 UTC
> Revision:     8afbf24b469158b714b36e84c6f4d4976c86fcd5
>
> Kotlin:       1.9.0
> Groovy:       3.0.17
> Ant:          Apache Ant(TM) version 1.10.13 compiled on January 4 2023
> JVM:          21 (Homebrew 21)
> OS:           Mac OS X 12.4 x86_64

When I run `java -v` it outputs an error, but I do have `jabba` installed and can switch versions if I need to, but I am unsure if it even wants me to switch the version my current shell is using or which version to switch it to...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the default version of pitest used by 1.9.0 of the gradle plugin. This is very old.

Either configure an explicit recent version of pitest

```
pitest {
    pitestVersion = '1.15.0' 
    ...
}
```

Or upgrade to the recent 1.15.0 release of the gradle plugin which uses pitest 1.15.0 by default.